# Question related to Suslin Problem

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I had the following curiosity/question related to the Suslin Problem. It would be very helpful if you could recommend to me some good literature on the topic. Thanks in Advance!

Suppose you have a non-empty set $(A, *)$ where $*$ is a binary relation that is transitive and antisymmetric. Additionally, suppose that:

(1) $(A, *)$ does not have a least nor a greatest element;

(2) $*$ is dense on $A$;

(3) $*$ is complete on $A$, in the sense that every non-empty bounded subset has a supremum and an infimum; and

(4) every collection of mutually disjoint non-empty open intervals in $(A, *)$ is countable

(Question:) Is $(A, *)$ necessarily order-isomorphic to the real line R?

Comment: The addition that $*$ is neither reflexive nor irreflexive is confusing here. If it doesn't matter, and it doesn't, then either *add* the $=$ inside or *remove it completely.* Just so you can conform to one of the two usual definitions of a partial order. You also not require that the order is linear, in which case just take two disjoint copies of $(0,1)$ (think two parallel lines on the plane), and you have an order which is dense, complete, satisfies (4) but could *never* be isomorphic to the reals.

Comment: Thank you @AsafKaragila! This is very helpful! Just one more follow-up: is it possible to embed an arbitrary  $\omega_2$-sequence/$\omega_1$-sequence  in such an $ A$?

Comment: Clearly not, since $\omega_1$ is a union of uncountably many open intervals.